# Google reviews from place ID

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-places, google-reviews

i'm very new to web programming so there's a lot of things that i don´t know.

I've searched about how to get google reviews from a place using only the place ID but there's no information.
I know that's possible because there's a wordpress plugin by trustindex that can do that exact thing but my question is:

is there a way to get google reviews only from the place ID using JavaScript, HTML and PHP?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First you need Google my business with api setup - https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup . Then get reviews with following examples - https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews

Comment: this reads unclear

Comment: Since the OP is asking what is the process and mention there is no information/documentation i have provided one from Google so he/she can start building its own script. What is unclear to you ? The question or the answer ? I guess the answer since you are commenting under my answer so if you need guidance or assist with something feel free to ask your own question.